# In django, how can I modify a batch sessions without request?

Tags: python, django, session

I want to modify a batch of django sessions in server part and create fields for django session so that I can put a list in each session.
Environment：django 1.11.3   python 3.5

1、how can I visit these sessions by clue of fields(like user id\phoneNO etc) without request ？

2、how can I set format of  sessions before request？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify sessions outside of a view using a [`SessionStore`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views). Assuming you are using database backed sessions, you could update a specific subset of sessions for a specific list of users, like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

interesting_user_ids = []  # ids of users you want to modify sessions for
new_data = []  # list that you want to add to each session

for session in Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gt=datetime.now()):
    store = SessionStore(session_key=session.session_key)
    if store.get('_auth_user_id') in interesting_user_ids:
        store['new_data'] = new_data
        store.save()
```

Obviously you'll need to populate the list of `interesting_user_ids` and `new_data` as appropriate.

Comment: in my Environment：django 1.11.3 python 3.5, it shows ' Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. '  It's too late here, I will try tomorrow.